# How to enumerate constant in Python 3

Tags: python-3.x, constants, enumeration

I want a easy form to define multiple constant and enumerate them, so that using only the name of every constant give me the value of the enumeration, similar to enum in C but in Python 3. For example:

```
harmonic=0
vrms=1
irms=2
.
.
.
and so
```

Comment: mmm  https://docs.python.org/3/library/enum.html

Comment: Hi @juliancaba, welcome to stackoverflow! Please try to be a bit more precise with your questions, this will help everybody in the end and also make it much more likely, that your questions get answered. Best wishes, Andreas

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> from enum import Enum
>>> class mycons(Enum):
...  vrms=1
...  irms=2
...  

>>> print(mycons.irms.name)
irms
>>> print(mycons.irms.value)
2
```